# Based on an input, how can I classify elements of a list into objects for classes?

Tags: python-3.x, list, class

I have the code:

```
class tune:
    def __init__(self, title, artist, duration):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.duration = duration
class play:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tracks = []

    def add(self, song):
    self.tracks.append[song]
    
    def look(self,song):
    print (self.artist,"-",self.title)

n=input() #number of input
song=play()
for i in range(n):
    x = input().split(',')
    song.title=x[1]
    song.artist=x[0]
    song.duration=x[2]
song.look()
```

for every input, i have to make it an object pertaining to its class and add it to the list. When song.look is called, it is supposed to print out the title and artist in the list. For example, if the input is:

```
2
Artic Monkeys,R U Mine?,324
Artic Monkeys,Do I wanna know?,253
```

when the program is executed it should output:

```
Artic Monkeys - R U Mine?
Artic Monkeys - Do I wanna know?
```

I don't know if i appended the inputs to its object respectively, did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You did not give much context on what the problem was, but looking at your code it was somewhat obvious. Try using this:

```py
class Tune:

    def __init__(self, title, artist, duration):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.duration = duration

class Play:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tracks = []

    def add(self, song):
        self.tracks.append(song)
    
    def look(self, song):
        for song in self.tracks:
            print(f"{song.artist} - {song.title}")

n = int(input("Enter the number of tracks to add"))
playlist = Play()

for i in range(n):
    title, artist, duration = input("Enter the title, artist, and duration of a track").split(',')
    song = Tune(title, artist, duration)
    playlist.add(song)

playlist.look()
```